# Write gzipped-already data into a file

Tags: python, unicode, gzip

I have a database with some of the data is binary (blob datatype in MySQL), which was actually webpages scrapped and gzipped. Now I want to extract them and write each record into a gzip file, which I'd assume to be doable - after all they are gzipped-data right?

The question is, however, how would I do that? By searching I could find a million of examples on how to write gzip file from *original* data, not gzipped one. Writing the gzipped string directly into a file doesn't result in a gzip file, not to mention I got a load of "ordinal not in range" exceptions.

Could you guys help? Thanks in advance. I'm a newbie to Python...

Edit: Here is the method I used:

```
def store_cache(self, content, news_id):
        if not content:
            return
        # some of the records may contain normal data (not gzipp-ed), hence this try block
        try:
            content = self.gunzip(content)
        except:
            return

        import gzip
        with gzip.open('static/cache/%s' % (self.base36encode(news_id), ), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(content)
            f.close()
```

This causes an exception:

```
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'> at /migrate
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u1edb' in position 186: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And this is the innermost traceback:

```
E:\Python27\lib\gzip.py in write
            self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffffL
```

Comment: why don't you post the code you have that saves the file and throws these errors? maybe someone can help you correct it.

Comment: Does it work if you simply write the binary data (from the MySQL blob) to a file with .gz extension?

Comment: No @Yannick, a UnicodeEncodeError appears all the time. I tried with codecs, utf-8 encoding/decoding and so on...

Comment: For some reason you seem to be getting unicode strings out of your database. Any chance that your BLOBs are actually TEXT objects in the database and you need to switch off `use_unicode` to get them out safely?

Comment: Hi Yannick, actually some of the blobs are unicode strings (not gzipped), but didn't I already put them into try...except block?

Comment: Could you show us `self.gunzip`?

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: **extract them** and then write them into a gzip file. There is nothing special about writing "from gzipped data": you un-gzip the data to get the original data, and then write the original data as if it were original data (because it is). The documentation shows you how to do these things.

However, gzip is just a compression format, not an archive format. It is not built to handle multiple files, so you must use something else to create a single file from the multiple inputs. Typically this is done by making a tar archive which is then gzipped. You can do this in Python using the `tarfile` module. Since your data will come from gzip-decompression streams, you will want to use the `TarFile.addfile(tarinfo, fileobj)` method to add them to the archive. You should be able to use the `gzip.GzipFile` instance as the `fileobj` to add this way.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. Let me (re)try just what Karl advised: uncompress the gzipped content and write it into a gzip file. Actually it's one file per record, so I won't need `tarfile` module.
Will keep you posted with the result.

Comment: OK I edited my question to include my last try, could you guys help again?